# How to differentiate timeout error and other `URLError`s in Python?

Tags: python, http, urllib2

How to differentiate timeout error and other `URLError`s in Python?

**EDIT**

When I catch a `URLError`, it can be `Temporary failure in name resolution` or `timeout`, or some other error? How can I tell one from another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use code like Option 2, below... but for a comprehensive answer, look at [Michael Foord's urllib2 page](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml)

If you use either option 1 or option 2 below, you can add as much intelligence and branching as you like in the except clauses by looking at `e.code` or `e.reason`

Option 1:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
req = Request(someurl)
try:
    response = urlopen(req)
except HTTPError, e:
    print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
    print 'Error code: ', e.code
except URLError, e:
    print 'We failed to reach a server.'
    print 'Reason: ', e.reason
else:
    # everything is fine
```

Option 2:

```
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import Request
# insert other code here...
    error = False
    error_code = ""
    try:
        if method.upper()=="GET":
            response = urlopen(req)
        elif method.upper()=="POST":
            response = urlopen(req,data)
    except IOError, e:
        if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
            #print 'We failed to reach a server.'
            #print 'Reason: ', e.reason
            error = True
            error_code = e.reason
        elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
            #print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
            #print 'Error code: ', e.code
            error = True
            error_code = e.code
    else:
        # info is dictionary of server parameters, such as 'content-type', etc...
        info = response.info().dict
        page = response.read()
```

Comment: Would you please tell me where can I look up the corresponding `reason` code for `timeout`?

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about an HTTP Timeout, which is e.code = 408 from an HTTPError

Comment: Maybe I should try e.reason == 'time out'. I read the source of `URLError`, whose `__str__` goes like `<urlopen error %s> % self.reason`, and in my traceback I can see `<urlopen error timed out>`.

Comment: There are several reasons for timeouts... I can't list them all, but the two possibilities we have so far are:
1.  Name Lookup, which is what I think you're seeing in URLError... in other words, urllib never connects to the server
2.  Server response timed out, which is the HTTP error I mentioned above.  In this case the server started the response, but failed to complete it before the HTTP session timed out.

You need to be very specific when trapping network issues...

Comment: I'm curious why you need to be so specific... in either case, you need to retry the connection in an hour or so... in the first case, it could be a temporary issue with DNS... in the second case, you hope that someone fixes whatever issues prevented the server from completing its response.

Comment: Thx, currently there are 3 kinds of URLError found in my log, name resolution, timeout and service not known. `timeout` is the most frequent one, so I want to detect it in my code and retry the connection. But I'm confused about how to do this, some said `isinstance(e.reason, socket.timeout)`, but I'm now sure if it's the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to differentiate timeout Error and other URLError

```
except URLError, e:
    if e.reason.message == 'timed out':
        # handle timed out exception
    else:
        # other URLError
```